# Windows XP running as OpenSSH server through cygwin. Can I remotely execute MS-DOS commands?

Tags: cygwin, ms-dos

I tried typing cmd or cmd.exe at the bash line which then takes to the DOS shell. But from there I tried executing something like trial.bat which contains some lines to access a series of executable commands, but to no avail. Is this the correct way to go about it? Thanks ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look for the pstools, which I think was part of the sysinternals suite. You can remotely execute a cmd line with those.